# Change In-app purchase from test to Production in playstore

Tags: react-native, google-play, in-app-purchase, billing

I created an app in React-native and added in-app purchases.
Problem is, it keeps showing the test cards even when the app is in production

I've tried "promoting the app from closed testing to production" on playstore but it still shows the test cards. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So I found out it was actually working properly on other phones.
It was still showing the test cards on my device because I added myself as a tester while the app was not yet in production.

So just remove yourself from the testing and it'll be fine